# Using the Rounding function in SQL

Tags: sql, function, rounding

```sql
SELECT track_id, name, ROUND(bytes/1000000,6) AS megabytes
  FROM track
 LIMIT 5;

Result
track_id    name                                          megabytes
1           For Those About To Rock (We Salute You)        11
2           ■■■■■ to the Wall                               5
3           Fast As a Shark                                 3
4           Restless and Wild                               4
5           Princess of the Dawn                            6
```

How do I get to show for megabytes to 6 decimal places. First one should be 11.170334.
I put in 6 for the round command

Comment: the DBMS is MySQL, isn't it..? (tag the DBMS please)

Comment: Try `/1000000.0`, you're likely dividing an integer by another integer, which in many DBMSs will evaluate to an integer.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

If the `bytes` field holds precision you are casting it to an integer when you divide by an integer. The easiest way to make this statement work is divide by a decimal like:

```
SELECT track_id, name, ROUND(bytes/1000000.0,6) AS megabytes
FROM track
LIMIT 5;
```

a better approach would be to do this in the thing making the query.
i.e. A web Page, excel, access etc.

Comment: Thank you Lasse now it makes sense to me.